# Migrating from IBM MQ to javax.jms.* (Weblogic)

Tags: oracle11g, jms, weblogic, mq, advanced-queuing

I've been looking for days about how one could migrate from using IBM Websphere MQ to rather only using the QueueManager within Weblogic 10.3.x server. This would save cost of licenses for IBM MQ. The closest I came was finiding an external link which stated that IBM examples existed that did something similar(moving away from MQ to standard jms libraries), but when I attempted to follow the link: http://www.developer.ibm.com/isv/tech/sampmq.html 
  it lead to a dead page :\

More specifically I am interested in

1. What classes to use in my attempts to replace the following, com.ibm.mq.* classes:

   - MQEnvironment
   - MQQueueManager
   - MQGetMessageOptions
   - MQPutMessageOptions
   - and other classes which don't have an obvious javax.jms.* alternative.
2. Some of the nuances & work-arounds I may encounter in this migration process.

The database we are forwarding the queue messages to is Oracle 11 Standard (with advanced queuing) if that changes anything, so basically we are looking to "cut out the middle-man", so to speak. Your learned responses will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have completed an application which supported both JBossMQ and MQSeries/WebSphere MQ.

The MQSeries specific classes I required were

```
import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory;
```

These were sufficient to create the `javax.jms.QueueConnection/TopicConnection`.

As for WebSphere MQ, I connected directly.
As for JBossMQ I looked up the factories using JNDI.

So on top of this there is only JMS.

1. So the first step is to rewrite your application so that *only* the initializing part uses WebSphere MQ specific classes (the ones I have listed above)
2. Replace the remaining MQ specific part with a JNDI/directory lookup for a `queue connection factory` provided by your application server
3. Remove the MQ series specific parts from your source.

Here is a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17441684/2390083) which shows how to send a message.

Comment: Thanks for this @Beryllium, but the goal here is to not use IBM MQ at all.. The existing system is dependant on IBM MQ, the proposed solution should not have IBM MQ at all anymore, and must use the in-built java messaging within Weblogic server, so "import com.ibm.mq..." must not be found in the code.. like ibms' MQException replaced with javax' MessageEOFException

Comment: Actually that was my intention, I've updated my answer to clarify this

Comment: Did you have to create a separate producer & consumer per queue or were you able to extract common components into a sort of QueueManager like the IBM proprietary one?

Comment: Once you have the `javax.jms.QueueConnection`, you can create all other JMS objects (session, queue, sender, message). I have organized this in some other (normal Java) classes; that's not really JMS specific, but it's a sort of queue manager.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the MQI api for MQ, to which there is no replacement at hand. There is no other way than to actually rewrite your MQ application logic to use the JMS API.

A good way might be to first migrate into JMS using the same WebSphere MQ server, since it allows you to verify your results in a reliable way.

You ask for what classes to replace say MQGetOptions with. There are no single 1-to-1 replacement (there are even some aspects of MQI that JMS cannot easily replace). Most of the MQPutOptions and other options are available by setting parameters on sessions and messages in JMS. You really need to understand the JMS api before trying this switch.

Then, when you have jms working with WebSphere MQ, you can do as Beryllium suggests, but swapping the libraries to Weblogic, switch any reference to `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;`, configuring the new parameters and pray to any a available god - press run :)

Comment: Thanks for this food for thought, @Petter ..this is quite a mission as there are hundreds of different queues that we are managing at present so the previous devs, naturally made reusable classes to manage these - the problem, however, is that IBM classes are exactly that - IBM specific. I guess there's no avoiding a rewrite - Coffee Me!