# Migrating IBM MQ to javax.jms.* implementation - How does MQOPEN translate to JMS API?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

How do you get the same effect as ibm's proprietary mq api's openOptions when using MQ with JMS api?

Is there even a concept of openOptions in the JMS API? If so, what is the equivilent in terms of the API classes/methods?

[Related stackoverflow question - migrating-from-ibm-mq-to-javax-jms-weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856662/migrating-from-ibm-mq-to-javax-jms-weblogic)

Comment: Please post your MQ code. It's hard to figure out which options you are using actually.

Comment: There is no code. this is a general question about the standards. I must not have been too clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges. Yes, both are fruit but they are completely different fruit.  There is no direct comparison between the 2.

1) A JMS session with "transacted" and "createSender" is basically an open output with syncpoint.
i.e.

```
// Open Options
int oo = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
// Put Msg Options
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
pmo.options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT + MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
```

2) A JMS session with "createReceiver" (non-transacted) is basically an open input.
i.e.

```
int oo = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
// Get Msg Options
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple example shows to how to send a `Message` (using JBoss MQ):

```
    final Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();
    initialContextProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    initialContextProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url",
            "jnp://localhost:1099");

    //

    final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);

    final QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic
            .lookup("XAConnectionFactory");

    final Queue queue = (Queue) ic.lookup("queue/A");

    //

    final QueueConnection queueConnection = qcf.createQueueConnection();

    final boolean transacted = false;
    final QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(
            transacted, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    final QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);

    final TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage("Hello");
    queueSender.send(textMessage);
```

so there are different options on different stages/levels:

- You normally need to have some properties for the JNDI lookup (to get the `InitialContext`).
- You have to lookup the factory and the queue by name using JNDI.
- There are some settings when you create the `QueueSession`: transacted, acknowledge.
- The usage is specified when you call `createSender`, `createReceiver`, `createBrowser` on the `QueueSession` instance.

Comment: Hmmm my question must not have been clear. I was asking more simply "how do you get the same effect as ibm's proprietary mq api's openOptions when using MQ with jms api?"